# KafkaConnect - JdbcSinkConnector - mapping fields columns

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I made transformation to load data from topics to a postgres database.

Is it possible to map a field of the record in a column with different name ?
As for example : field_x > column_field_x

```
"fields.whitelist":"field_x"
```

Today this field is trying to go a column "field_x" but I would like it to go on "column_field_x"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transformation "ReplaceField" https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#replacefield